# How to automatically select text when user clicks on a link?

Tags: google-chrome, hyperlink, google-chrome-extension

In my extension, users can select text and right click which displays a menu with some options for the extension. A simple selectionText captures the selected text:

```
ocd.selectionText
```

But the same menu is not displayed if the user right clicks on a link without selecting the text.

- How can I display my context menu when the user clicks on a link without selecting the text?
- How can I capture the link text at the same time?

Answer (score 2):

You need to add the `links` context to your parameters when you create your menu:

http://code.google.com/chrome/extensions/contextMenus.html#method-create

...then you will get `linkUrl ( optional string )
If the element is a link, the URL it points to.`

Comment: Once you have the url you can cycle through the 'a' elements to find that URL - once you have the element you can get the text. Is it possible that the same URL may be used more than once but with different text? Not sure what you'd do in that case.